# Alternative reference request for Kato's Perturbation Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, perturbation-theory

I am studying Analytic Perturbation Theory from Kato's book.But sometimes I find it really difficult to follow.(e.g. In Chapter 2 , he directly talks about algebraic singularities without defining it and many more things). Is there any other book which covers same topics in more detail ?

Comment: What operators are you mostly interested in?

Comment: I want to understand general theory.

Comment: If he covers them with an algebraic geometric flavour, perhaps it's better to check the references in Murdock's classic book in chapter 1 page 79. One such book is Singularities and Groups in Bifurcation Theory. I haven't read this book, I didn't even finish reading Murdock's book.